# .NET Maui iOS - System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.' Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2

Tags: xamarin.ios, dotnet-httpclient, maui, .net-maui

This Library / code works fine in Xamarin Forms latest. I'm working on bringing an App over to .NET Maui and am receiving this error. Is there something about .NET Maui HTTP that is less supported than Xamarin iOS?

```
   at System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler.get_SupportsRedirectConfiguration()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object , BindingFlags , Binder , Object[] , CultureInfo )
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.InvokeNativeHandlerMethod(String , Object[] )
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetSupportsRedirectConfiguration()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.get_SupportsRedirectConfiguration()
   at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateAndConfigureClientHandler()
   at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHandler(CreateHttpClientArgs args)
   at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient(CreateHttpClientArgs args)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceCredential..ctor(Initializer initializer)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential..ctor(Initializer initializer)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateServiceAccountCredentialFromParameters(JsonCredentialParameters credentialParameters)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialFromParameters(JsonCredentialParameters credentialParameters)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialFromJson(String json)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.FromJson(String json)
```

Code:

```
    string content = File.ReadAllText("secret.json");

    var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(content).CreateScoped(new string[] { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets });

    new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential
    });
```

Comment: Did you by any chance find a solution to this?

Comment: This is being caused due to problems with Native HttpClient Handler in iOS
More details at https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/14632